# java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism guidelines to choose the right size of parallelism

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

any guidelines or factors should I consider while setting the JVM arguments for parallelism. java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism. Our perf team is setting this up to 50 to check the application performance. I would like to check whats the high and low sealing available for this property.

Comment: This value does already have a reasonable default.

Comment: I believe it's equivalent to number of cores, whats the high sealing I can go up to.